# Detecting which side of a square collides with collision detection

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision-detection

I am using Corona SDK to detect collisions. I have no problem detecting whether the collision was to the left of the square or to the right using the following code:

```
if (event.other.x < displayObj.x)
```

the collision code:

```
function box:collision(event)
  if event.phase == "ended" then 
    if event.other.id and event.other.id == "c" then 
      --need to detect top collision 
      test = 1 
    end
```

How do I detect whether the top of the square has collided with something?

Comment: Show us your implementation of `function onCollision(event)`. Now I don't understand why can't you use `.y`.

Comment: put it in your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear algebra! Vectors and the dot product are very useful for figuring out what you want. You can find more indepth information if you google: `Half-space test dot product`

Assuming you have a box named `A` and collision point `B`, with positions `(A.x,A.y)` and `(B.x,B.y)` and the forward direction of the box determined by `(A.dirX, A.dirY)` you can determine if point B is in front or behind box A's direction like this:

1. Get a vector from position A to B and normalize it:

   `vectorToBNormalized = normalize((B.x,B.y)-(A.x,A.y))`
2. Use the dot product of `vectorToBNormalized` and `A`'s forward vector to determine if B is in front of behind.

   `result = dot(vectorToBNormalized, normalize(A.dirX, A.dirY))`

> If the result is less than 0 then: B is behind A; If the result is greater than 0 then: B is in front of A.

To find out if the box B is left or right of box A, repeat the process but using a right-facing vector instead of a forward vector for box A. For example, if up is defined by `(0, 1)`, then right would be `(1, 0)`.

This way you can determine if the point of collision is behind/infront, or left/right.